# How to create a DataStore?

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService('DataStoreService')
local playerData = DataStoreService:GetDataStore('PlayerData')

-- Erstellt Leaderboard
local function onPlayerJoin(player)
    
    local leaderstats = Instance.new('Folder')
    leaderstats.Name = 'leaderstats'
    leaderstats.Parent = player
    
    local clicks = Instance.new('IntValue')
    clicks.Name = 'Clicks'
    clicks.Value = 0
    clicks.Parent = leaderstats
    
    local rebirths = Instance.new('IntValue')
    rebirths.Name = 'Rebirths'
    rebirths.Value = 0
    rebirths.Parent = leaderstats
    
    -- Wenn ein Nutzer verlassen hat das die daten gespeichert wurden
    local playerUserId = 'Player_'..player.UserId
    local data = playerData:GetAsync(playerUserId)
    if data then
        clicks.Value = data['Clicks']
        rebirths.Value = data['Rebirths']
    else  -- Wenn user das erste mal joint das value 0 ist
        clicks.Value = 0
        rebirths.Value = 0
    end
end

local function create_table(player)
    local player_stats = {}
    for _, stat in pairs(player.leaderstats:GetChildren()) do
        player_stats[stat.Name] = stat.Value
    end
    return player_stats
end

local function onPlayerExit(player)
    local player_stats = create_table(player)
    local success, err = pcall(function ()
        local playerUserId = 'Player_'..player.UserId
        playerData:SetAsync(playerUserId, player_stats)
    end)
    
    if not success then
        warn('Could not save data')
    end
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(onPlayerJoin)
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(onPlayerExit)
```

I tried to make a DataStore that stores the values of the leaderboard into a data that returns everytime if i rejoin. But it doesnt work and idk why. Im kinda new into lua programming but u guys can help me :D thanks.

Comment: Heyo, when you ask a question on StackOverflow, it's not enough to simply say that something doesn't work. Be specific about what isn't working. What error are getting? What are you getting back from the pcall? Is the data saving properly? Try to debug the problem and give us some more information.

Comment: Have you enabled data stores for Roblox studio? If not: 1.In the Home tab of the menu bar, navigate to the Settings section and click Game Settings. The Game Settings menu displays. 2.In the left-hand navigation of the Game Settings menu, click Security. 3.Enable the Enable Studio Access to API Services toggle. 4.Click the Save button.